# XmlHTTPRequest not performing set-cookie

Tags: javascript, curl, cookies, cross-domain

I am trying to make an API call to a service (on a different domain) and in its response headers, there are some `Set-Cookie` headers.

And in the response, I have an URL that I need to hit again along with these cookies. But the browser does not seem to respect these cookies and they do not get sent.

Now what I tried to do was, after making the XmlHTTPRequest, I used `document.cookie` to set the cookies (cookies were also available as part of the API response) along with the domain. And even then the subsequent request (normal http) would not use these cookies.

Now, if I try to visit the page of the actual service, they set cookies in my browser under their domain and now my requests start working properly!

What else I did? I got the cookies and URL from the API response and used `cURL` to make the request. Voila it worked!

How do I acheive the same with JavaScript. Is it because you cant set cookies for a different domain or something?

Comment: Bunch of stuff about cookies and cross origin requests on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :) @Quentin